# How do I plug in my colorramp so white will be embossed gold and black will be engraved darker silver carving on my silver kettle? Mock-up in middle

Tags: displacement, height-map, bump

The gold and darker colors I'd prefer to be their own material, and the silver Kettle will show out at 50% Grey. Blender 2.92.0

[image: kettle]

I am unsure where to plug in the colorramp, and how the gold material and dark engraved material should be mixed in: [image: nodes]

Comment: Do I get it right, the kettle overall should be silver, the words "gold bump" should be embossed on the kettle in golden color, and the "dark etch" is etched in with black (or dark blue) color? And at the bottom left of the screenshot, the _Image Texture_ node is the image we see on the bottom right?

Comment: Yes that is correct! The gold and darker colors I'd prefer to be their own material too (i made two example ones in my bottom screenshot, the two nodes to the left), not just the silver kettle in different tints of colors. It just came our like that in the mockup. I will probably add some different scratch surfaces to the gold, silver, and etching individually. But if simple colors makes explaining easier then that's okay! Also I am switched to render mode before anyone points out.

Comment: Actually you can do it with three different material setups and combine them, but you can also do it in one and use the image texture for different things like roughness etc. I'll try to create an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the image texture with different *Color Ramps* to drive all kinds of values. In my example, I've used *Greater Than* nodes to split the three grey values up to mix different colors created by *Noise Textures*. Of course you can use the mix factor to blend many more options or shaders.

I also used the image texture in combination with a *Color Ramp* for the *Metallic* input... I decided the gold and silver should be metallic = 1 and the etched part is dielectric = 0 (by the way, for realistic results never use values between 0 and 1, a surface is either dielectric or metallic, values inbetween should only be used for artistic / aesthetic reasons).

The *Roughness* is controlled by the image texture and a ramp, too. For the black/etched parts I made it absolutely rough by setting it to 1 in the ramp, the grey/silver part I made  not too glossy with a value of 0.3 and the gold I made more shiny with 0.05 (of course you can also plug values into *Specular* etc.)

Last but not least I've used the texture for the displacement of course. I left it as it is, so the etched part is indented, the silver is the overall height and the gold is buckled up. Without a ramp or anything, the overall *Scale* in the *Displacement* also controls the range between the deep and the high parts. Put another ramp in there to change the relations to each other.

All in all you have to play around with those values, see what fits best and where to put the color stops on those ramps. A good way to start is take one ramp set to constant and use it to convert the greyscale image to three bright different colors like red, green, blue and see how you have to manipulate them so that they refer to the correct parts.

Then you can use this basic color ramp and give the stops the values you need or decide how you can address them for mixing factors etc. You dont need them to constant, but sometimes this helps to better outline the different areas (especially when you have antialiasing or artifacts).

[image]

Render result:
[image: kettle render]

Node setup:
[image: kettle material]

EDIT: Here just two quick examples how an additional *Color Ramp* could be used to make extreme differences between the between highest and lowest displacement areas.

[image: kettle displacement]

Or you could try to make the silver part look like it's brushed metal (just a quick setup, not meant to be perfect) by plugging some noise limited to the grey area in the *Normal* input of the *Principled BSDF*.

[image: kettle brushed metal]

Comment: niiiiiiiiiiiiiiice! ;)

Comment: @Chris I just edited some more options in and updated the file to contain the additions.

Comment: This definitely look like the result I want! I downloaded your blend file and replaced your included texture with my goldbump/darketch and this is how it looks in render port: https://i.imgur.com/4HzesoS.png and in materials port: https://i.imgur.com/9GwIuoz.png Any idea what I am missing? I will try to setup your nodes in my main kettle project and see if I will succeed.

Comment: Actually I don't know why it is purple in the material preview - I test it and it's the same in my file. The only thing I could do was to copy all nodes in a new material and now it works, I've updated the file. For the different looking render: if you replaced my texture but left everything else as it is, then maybe the color ramps have to be modified to fit your texture. That's what I meant by saying play around with the values and color stops - maybe even plug the texture into a color ramp with bright different colors like red / green / blue to see if the areas are separated as expected.

Comment: Oh, and I see: you not just replaced the image texture in the node, you've taken a new node. In you _Image Texture_ node, the _Color Space_ is set to _sRGB_, while mine is set to _Non-Color_. That is important, because sRGB values are not linear. If you want to use a greyscale texture for anything else but as actual color it's best to set it to _Non-Color_. Of course it would work with sRGB, too - but it transforms black to white differently. For this reason the color stops in a ramp get slightly different values to convert.

Comment: I am getting closer! I fixed sRGB to Non-color, that helped. I realised now I had the material set to Bump only this whole time so now it has displacement and bump. My setup: https://i.imgur.com/sTrWh4l.png and engraving with Bump only: https://i.imgur.com/3RMKJr2.png I replaced the texture with the work-in-progress one which leans more towards the result I want. Any idea what values I should play around with here now to make it less jagged and more smooth so I can see the depth properly? Or is the map too low res? (3k x 2k )

Comment: I guess a big part of the issue is a low-res texture. Of course you could take Photoshop or something to smooth the edges, but it won't be geeat. Another thing is, when you use a ramp set to constant there will always a harsh transition, but a higher resolution will help there as well.

Comment: Should I try switch one of the ramps (which ramp? the gold and black?) to linear, and also maybe make the etchings more soft around the edges in Photoshop?

Comment: Hard to tell what works best... I could only use try and error...

Comment: Found out I had Adaptive Subdiv turned off, it's on now. Loving the result so far: https://i.imgur.com/6doam1W.png Any idea how I can make the edges of the bumps more soft/pillowed like pictured:  https://i.imgur.com/HxMvxD1.png or will that be another node rabbit hole better suited for a separate question thread?

Answer (score 1):

you can use this setup - blend file is below

[image]

[image]

[image]

ok, update: now with two different materials:

[image]

Comment: Okay, you are faster than I am. That's the quick version, to really make them three different materials you have to add some more nodes... for example, the etched part is way to glossy and you can even drive the metallic setting with the texture. Or if you want to vary the colors a little more... And why use a color ramp with yellow color for the  displacement when you don't re-use the other one anyway?

Comment: Thank you ;) yes you are right, could be better, but I hope he is happy to learn how to do it and does not want the „perfect“ solution.

Comment: Well, according to this statement in the comments: "The gold and darker colors I'd prefer to be their own material too (i made two example ones in my bottom screenshot, the two nodes to the left", I thought a more complex setup would be preferred.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann: you are right -> i updated my answer

Comment: If you don't mind I would like to see a complex setup too. Although what Chris showed looks okay it's not the result I am looking for, the bumps aren't sticking out - neither on the edges of the mesh. I am looking for bumps like the bumps in the Donut tutorial that will show up in the render. I also tried your updated node setup but I don't see where my silver kettle node will be?

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann ok, now it‘s your turn 

Comment: I'll make my turn soon - my work keeps me from finishing it ;) The bumps can't stick out with the above setup, because there's yellow for the bump and white for the kettle. Since displacement uses greyscales and yellow is darker than white, the gold is etched in but less than the darker etched part.

Comment: @Chris Your new material still has the yellow in the displacement color ramp, so the gold part will not stick out but be indented.